# Getting "0" in logcat for my SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

```
 private void aeroMindMaps(List<Details> mList) {  

    for (Details bean : details) {
        final String urlChar = bean.getUrl();
       final int idno = bean.getId();     

        SharedPreferences pref =getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edt = pref.edit();
        edt.putString("urlid",urlChar);
        edt.putInt("urlidno",idno);
        edt.commit();

       Log.e("idno for mindmaps01",String.valueOf(idno));
```

*I am getting first log correct and in next log getting 0,I wrote log only one time but getting the values 4 times in logcat*

Output of my sharedPreference is:

```
04-15 13:59:25.480 13612-13612/com.example.****.tabview E/idno for     mindmaps01: 68
04-15 13:59:25.547 13612-13612/com.example****.tabview E/idno for mindmaps01: 0
04-15 13:59:25.625 13612-13612/com.example.****.tabview E/idno for mindmaps01: 68
04-15 13:59:25.691 13612-13612/com.example.****.tabview E/idno for mindmaps01: 0
```

Comment: Maybe the function which includes the code is invoked many times.

Comment: but why I am getting "0" the second time.And when I pass the value in next activity I get "0".

Comment: Show whole code please. I can't see where `idno` is assigned a value.

Comment: Remove MODE_PRIVATE flag, and share please Details's code

Comment: @Movsar MODE_PRIVATE has nothing to do with the behaviour that is described....isn´t it?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yeah, you're right, but the Details's code would be useful

Comment: @ShwetabhSingh does the value of urlChar also change??

Comment: Detail is my getter and setter class,I am fetching JSON data from URL .If I try to get any other data they are coming only one time.

Comment: @Sanoop no, the other data is coming only one time

Comment: @Shwetabh It´s not exact clear what your problem is. Is your problem that you are getting 0 value but you are expecting another value, or is your problem that the output comes up 4 times? `I am getting first log correct and in next log getting 0,I wrote log only one time but getting the values 4 times in logcat` ....<-- little bit confusing...

Comment: @ShwetabhSingh check if the program gets needed JSON string for a few times in a row. I mean, check whether 0 comes from your code, or from the web

Comment: and also y is the code in a for each loop, Update the preference after For each completes.  Correct me if am wrong @ShwetabhSingh

Comment: Yes@MovsarBekaev I also think that URL is making the problem.By the way, I changed MODE_PRIVATE to 0 and it worked correctly the first time but after on getting same error

Comment: @Opiatefuchs both the things is my problem getting 0 value but I am expecting another value and also that the output comes up 4 times.

Comment: well, the ouput comes up 4 times because it is a for loop. So i guess the details list is filled with 4 items. And some of these items have value 0. Why they have 0 value is not clear from your code, so I think we have to see how the list is filled...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Exactly..

Comment: Anyway @ShwetabhSingh you are updating the prefernce.. y are u placing in inside the for loop.. try it outside

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, as I mention above the problem, is with the URL,changing the URL only shows the result correctly in the logcat and also shows only one output.

Comment: output     // 04-15 15:03:04.026 25305-25305/com.example.*****.tabview E/idno for mindmaps01: 72   *************
    04-15 15:03:04.026 25305-25305/com.example.*****.tabview E/URL value: upload/13/safety & first aid.docx

Comment: then it depends what you are fetching from the URL. I think here nobody is really understanding what the problem is, so please rework your question and be more clear with detailed code preview....